# N shortest tours in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, tsp

I'm searching for papers dealing with the problem of finding not just the shortest tour in the graph (TSP) but finding N shortest tours. Somewhat surprisingly, I didn't find any mention of it, anywhere. I might be searching under a wrong name.

Comment: Not sure what protocol is on stackexchange regarding unanswered questions, but I am still very interested in the answer!

Comment: Perhaps a related notion is the ASP-completeness (Another Solution Problem completeness) formalized by [Takayuki Yato](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.74.6324&rep=rep1&type=pdf): for a given instance $x$ of  and a solution $s$ to it, find a solution to $x$ other than $s$. In particular in its paper it is proved that Hamiltonian cycle problem on grid graphs with deg < 4 is ASP-complete, since TSP is a generalization, it should be ASP-complete, too.